# How do I put a custom validation message for a "greater_than" property from my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5, locale

I'm using Rails 5.  In my model, I have this validation rule

```
      validates :price, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }
```

for one of my fields.  I want to create a custom validation error message but this isn't displaying for my ./config/locales/en.yml file

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        my_record:
          attributes:
        ...
            price:
              greater_than: "Please etner a valid number for price."
```

When I try and load my app, I get the error below

```
can not load translations from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/config/locales/en.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/config/locales/en.yml): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 30 column 1>
```

What's the right way to set up the custom error message in my locales file?

Comment: enter is misspelled, but also which line is line 30 in your yaml? It looks like your YAML is invalid with a syntax error on that line

Comment: you need to validate your YAML file first, you may try this site yamllint.com

Comment: There were tabs instead of whitespace which caused the error.  Come on Rails!  Give me an error message I can understand!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a YAML parsing issue caused by bad formatting or syntax. Check that you don't have any single quotes anywhere and your indentation is correct at line 29, 30 and 31